# Лидирующий "0" в std::atoi

Tags: c++

Вот такой код выводит "10" в консоль (VS2017):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = std::atoi("010");
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Т.е. ведущий ноль игнорируется, но на сколько это стандартизировано?
[Здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) и [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) не нашел.

Comment: А какой результат ожидается?

Comment: @VTT 10 либо 0 (ошибка преобразования), но чтобы наверняка.

Comment: Еше раз: что вы хотели получить? Интерпретарцию как восьмиричное представление? Или что-то другое? Как именно вы хотели "не игнорировать" ведущий ноль? Что вы имеете в виду под "чтобы наверняка"? Данные код "наверняка" дает `10`. Чем это не "наверняка"?

Comment: @AnT не принципиально какое, важно чтобы детерминированное. Т.е. у меня сейчас 10, будет ли так же на других компиляторах

Comment: Да, будет давать 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно стандарту С11 функция `int atoi(const char *nptr);` эквивалентна `(int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)` за исключением поведения при ошибке.

В описании последней помимо прочего сказано:

> ... only letters and digits whose ascribed values are less than that of base are permitted.

`0` является валидной десятичной цифрой, таким образом наличие предшествующих нулей не должно влиять на результат вызова.

Наличие нуля в начале могло бы влиять при автоматическом определении основания системы счисления, т.е. при указании `base = 0`, но для `atoi` это не актуально.

Answer (score 3):

Это стандарту соответствует - `atoi` работает с десятичным представлением.

Если хотите, чтобы префикс `0` означал восьмеричное значение, а `0x` - шестнадцатеричное - посмотрите, например, в сторону [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) или [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) с указанием основания системы счисления 0.

P.S. Кстати, по вашей же ссылке четко сказано -

*takes an optional initial plus or minus sign followed by as many* **base-10** *digits as possible, and interprets them as a numerical value.*

Comment: Это да. Но там же написано, что  если "not a valid integral number" то вернет 0. Т.е. вопрос в том, валидна ли запись числа как "010".

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, *010₁₀ = 0 * 10³ + 1 * 10² + 0 * 10¹* , так что формально всё корректно.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan В десятичной системе абсолютно валидна - 0 сотен, 1 десяток, 0 единиц...

Comment: @Harry @Arhad Формально да, но речь же идет о записи числа в определенном языке программирования, т.е. должна быть какая-то бумашка официальная. Например в записи `int a = 010;` ведущий нолик имеет особое значение, не относящееся к сотням.

Comment: См. мой ответ - `atoi` работает **всегда** в десятичной системе счисления... А в ней 0 - это и есть 0.

Comment: @Harry [Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) говорит "It is generally assumed that, if n > 0, the first digit is not zero", насколько в плюсах особенный случай, чтобы считать лидирующий ноль корректным?

Comment: Может, как намек, вас устроит описание `strtol`, где говорится, что ведущий 0 рассматривается особым образом только если основание указано как 0? Т.е. ведущий ноль *разрешен*, просто в общем случае рассматривается как обычная десятичная цифра. И еще - к вашему о "речь же идет о записи числа в определенном языке" - вы неправы, потому что речь идет **не** о числовом литерале, а о строке, вводимой, например, обычны пользователем. И было бы, мягко говоря, странно, если бы нужно было разбираться, на каком языке написана программа, прежде чем вводить данные :) Опять же в Вики речь идет о выводе n...